# can I bypass the "test connection" aspect of ssrs report builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm attempting to edit a query of an SSRS report and report builder won't allow me to save because it has issues connecting to the database server.

Can I bypass this "feature" so that I can just save the report?  I'm not even adding fields, just tying to update a query so that it can run with a new set of data.  I've even ran the query just fine in management studio.

Our current solution is to just edit the file inside of a text editor, but I'd rather move away from that, if possible...